# BigCommerce API - Gift Certificates

Tags: bigcommerce

Are Gift Certificates supported through the API in any way? I wasn't able to find anything in the documentation or by searching online. I see that Coupons are covered by the API, but not Gift Certificates (that I see).

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard back from BigCommerce support on this issue through email. I am copying the response here for those that may search this in the future.

===================

There is not an API resource to recover gift certificate data at this time either.  It is easiest to find this in the Control Panel if you are looking for a particular Gift Certificate.

In the API, though, you could determine if a certain order had used a gift certificate or not.  Orders from the API will have a 'gift_certificate_amount' field to show how much of the order was paid with a gift certificate.  It will not tell you the code for the gift certificate though, in case that is important to you.